# Is this "string pattern matching" algorithm? Or something else?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic, pattern-matching

I am not even sure it's called pattern matching, but I would like to do something similar to there rules:

I have "objects" that have a "capability" attribute which is a sequence of names separated by spaces. For example:

```
a.capability = "" // no pattern
b.capability = "foo"
c.capability = "bar"
d.capability = "foo bar"
e.capability = "bar lol truc bidule"
```

(assume that each object must have a different pattern than other objects)

Then I have a global context object which also have such attribute:

```
context.capability = ""  // 1
// OR
context.capability = "foo"  // 2
// OR
context.capability = "bar"  // 3
// OR
context.capability = "bar foo"  // 4
// OR
context.capability = "lol"  // 5
```

Now, we want to select only one unique object that "best match" the context capability.
For this we follow this rule:

1. if an object have no pattern AND the context have no pattern, this object is selected;
2. if an object have no pattern AND the context have a pattern, this object is selected if no other object matches;
3. if an object have exactly the same pattern names as the context, it is selected;
4. the object with the most count of pattern names contained in the context patterns is selected;

For example:

- in context case 1) : `a` would be selected;
- in context case 2) : `b` would be selected;
- in context case 3) : `c` would be selected;
- in context case 4) : `d` would be selected;
- in context case 5) : `e` would be selected;

I'm writing this without even testing if this rules works, it's just an draft of what I would like to define.

My questions:

1. How do you call this kind of algorithm? (to allow me to do future research with the right name)
2. Are there already defined such a rules? It looks generic enough that someone could have defined similar rules before, but I can't find anything like that other than parts of language standard defining overloading rules (like the C++ standard);
3. Are there studies exploring the properties of such algorithm/rules? I an not certain that it's the right way to go for my use case but it seems likely the right solution. However I have no experience implementing this kind of language feature so I would like to see some data on what problem I might expect (but I can't find anything so far).

A friend suggested to look into some books about AI, expert systems and language designer and compiler implementation. However some guidance on how to find data on this particular way of doing would help a lot.

Comment: Are the words always written in a given order? As an example, is bar always guaranteed to come before foo? In both the context and the object? If not, is the order in which the values are written important? As an example, is "bar foo" equivalent to "foo bar"? I believe rule 4 implies that the ordering isn't important but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @ZeBlob Good question. At first I was thinking no it's not important, but I have no idea yet of the implication of adding order as a kind of priority. Now that you say this I remember Valve doing a presentation about this kind of stuff. I'll have to search for it. For now just assume that order is not important, only matching values are (like if it was a list of values).

Comment: There's a lot of problem context missing. How many objects do you expect to have? How many contexts? How many different capabilities? How many capabilities per context do you expect? How many capabilities per object? Can contexts or objects have the same capability listed more than once? Is the answer object to a query ever "too far away" from the context to be useful? Are the capabilities, contexts, or objects known at compile time? Is there a setup phase where pre-processing can be done? What platforms are you targeting? What are your performance goals? (Memory vs. processor)

Comment: Don't hit-and-run downvote. Explain why, please.

Comment: @Kaganar 1 to N objects, 1 unique context, 1 capability per object/context but it contain 0 to n values (I should have presented it as a list of values, think about it like that). The values themselves are not important, any value can be in any capability of any object or context. A value duplicated in the list is considered like if there was only one occurrence. I don't understand the too far away concept. However, there might be ambiguity if there are more than one matching objects, which I assumed there is not in the description. The question is independent of all your question though.

Comment: @Kaganar To be clear, none of my question is asking for implementation. I'm looking for information about what is this kind of algorithm and if there is data about how it behaves.

Comment: A friend suggested to look into some books about AI, expert systems and language designer and compiler implementation. Will do but it will take time...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but after thinking about it there's several ways in which I could frame the problem:

- Document retrieval (such as used in search engines -- how do they rank disjunctive queries so quickly?)
- *Non-metric* [nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) (link is for the common metric version)
- [0-1 linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns)

As such, I don't think there's one term for this problem -- it's too interesting to too many fields. There's certainly plenty of studies between the three fields (e.g. Google):

- [Document retrieval](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20disjunctive%20query%20document%20ranking&aq=f&oq=fast%20disjunctive%20query%20document%20ranking)
- [Non-metric nearest neighbor](https://www.google.com/search?q=non-metric%20nearest%20neighbor&aq=f&oq=non-metric%20nearest%20neighbor)
- [0-1 linear programming](https://www.google.com/search?q=binary%20linear%20programming&aq=f&oq=binary%20linear%20programming)